# SQL Server Email Alert Notifications

Tags: sql-server, email, notifications

Our DBA team gets atleast 500 sql server email notifications a day.  Does anyone know of a way to improve this process. Currently each dba wastes about 20 mins a day going through these and most of them are login in failures

Comment: Why not use reporting services? Put notifications into a database
and use reporting services to view on a webpage.
Microsoft give an example:
"Reporting Services LogViewer"
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24774

Answer (score 0):

Login errors come in the Severity 14 level, just ignore them.  Run a job once a day to scrape for login errors related to 'SA'.  You definitely do not want a hacker trying over and over again.

I have the same issue, we have 50 servers and 1000 plus alerts a day.  Some we need to respond to and others are just user errors.

```
Subject: SQL Server Alert System: 'Alert For Severity 14' occurred on \\SERVER

DATE/TIME:  12/13/2013 3:38:40 PM

DESCRIPTION:    Login failed for user 'USER'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: 10.10.10.63]

COMMENT:    (None)

JOB RUN:    (None)
```